# Finding files in specific folder in different directories

Tags: c#, find, directory

I need to find a lot of files (images) in a specific folder (for exemple CR7), in different directories.
Imagine I have a network share that I have to find and display all images in that specific folder (CR7). CR7 folder can be found in different places like:
`\\share\folder01\CR7` or: `\\share\folder01\folder02\CR7` or anything else.
What I have is this, but results from `filesList` dont go to datagridview:

```
public partial class FormProcuraFotos : Form
{
    DataTable tableWithPhotos;
    public FormProcuraFotos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += this.Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the new DataTable to be used
        tableWithPhotos = new DataTable();
        tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Filenames");
        tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Ctrl+C");
        //Find files on a specific folder (CR7)
        string allDir = @"\\server\folder01";
        var CR7Directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(allDir, "CR7", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> extensions = new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".bmp", ".png", ".tiff", ".gif" };
        List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var dir in CR7Directories)
        {
            List<string> FileNames = new DirectoryInfo(dir).EnumerateFiles(dir)
                                                           .Where(x => extensions.Contains(x.Extension))
                                                           .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            filesList.AddRange(FileNames);
        }
        // And now here we will add all the files that it has found into the DataTable
        foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
        {
            DataRow row = tableWithPhotos.NewRow();
            row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
            row[1] = entryFiles;
            tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        var formToOpen = new FormResultadosFotos(tableWithPhotos);
        formToOpen.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? _"Some idea how to solve this problem?"_ _What_ problem?

Comment: You need a recursive function for that :D

Comment: @TimSchmelter: [may be] he is looking for images under folder `CR7` but the code will gave him all image files under the base directory that he specified.

Comment: I only need to find those files (about 2000-3000) in those specific folders and not search all images on all directories. I think this way, I can reduce time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to split the execution by following steps:

- Get all Directories with name `"CR7"` under the specified folder by specifying `"CR7"` as `searchPattern`.
- Now you have all CR7 folder paths, Iterate through those collection and Get List of files and filter them based on the extension list, in each CR7 directory.

Can you please try this and let me know whether it solved your issues:

```
string allDir = @"\\share\folder01";
var CR7Directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(allDir, "CR7", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<string> extensions = new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".bmp", ".png", ".tiff", ".gif" };
List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
foreach (var dir in CR7Directories)
{
    List<string> FileNames = new DirectoryInfo(dir).EnumerateFiles(dir)
                                                   .Where(x => extensions.Contains(x.Extension))
                                                   .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    filesList.AddRange(FileNames);
}
```

Comment: Take a look to my first post. I edited the code. The program runs fine but the results do not appear in the datagridview. I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: @PauloFerreira: modifying and extending question after getting answer is not fair. The actual question as not related to grid binding issues. That may be another issue in your code and which will be a different question

Comment: I'm just trying to show the problem that has arisen in the meantime. I apologize.